# Jquery show / hide DIV and make it blink when it show

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I am creating a div default hidden and when I click a link it show (display) a warning div, this works fine but I want the div to blink too

Here is what I have

The text link to show the div

```
<a class="buttons" href="#" onclick="show(this)">join us</a>
```

Now the hidden div to display when we click the link above

```
<div id="warning" style="display:none;">SHOW THIS DIV ...</div>
```

And now the JQuery script

```
<script>
    function show(x){
        $('#warning').show();
        setInterval(blink, 100);
    };

</script>
```

The thing is that the div starts hidden when I click on the link it show the div but does not blink... How to make it blink when it shows ?

Comment: what you mean by blink? change background? border?

Comment: Maybe try this $(this).effect("highlight", {}, 3000);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change your show function removing the timer and using fadein/out:

```
    function show(x){
        $('#warning').show().fadeOut(100, function(){
            $(this).fadeIn(100, function(){
                show(this);
            });
        });
    };
```

The snippet:

```js
function show(x){
  $('#warning').show().fadeOut(100, function(){
    $(this).fadeIn(100, function(){
      show(this);
    });
  });
};

function stop(x) {
  $('#warning').stop();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>

<a class="buttons" href="#" onclick="show(this)">join us</a>
<a class="buttons" href="#" onclick="stop(this)">Stop blinking</a>
<div id="warning" style="display:none;">SHOW THIS DIV ...</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

As I like CSS3 solutions instead of js animations, there is my example how to solve it. It will not works for every browser, but it is still small issue for this type of animations.

```js
function show(x) {
  $('#warning').addClass('show');
};
```

```css
@keyframes example {
    0%   {opacity: 1;}
    25%  {opacity: 0;}
    50%  {opacity: 1;}
    75%  {opacity: 0;}
    100% {opacity: 1;}
}
#warning {
  position:absolute;
  top:-20000px;
  left:-20000px;
  opacity:0;
}
#warning.show {
  position:static;
  animation: example 1s linear 250ms;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="buttons" href="#" onclick="show(this)">join us</a>


<div id="warning">SHOW THIS DIV ...</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

[There is a nice blink plugin for jquery, try it](https://antiyes.com/2009/08/24/jquery-blink-plugin/)

For example:

```
$('#warning').blink();
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey why do you not need Jquery Toggle function?

```js
function show(x){
        setInterval( toggle, 100);
    };

function toggle(){
$('#warning').toggle()
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="buttons" href="#" onclick="show(this)">join us</a>
<div id="warning" style="display:none;">SHOW THIS DIV ...</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Dont know what you mean by 'blink' but here is an idea on how to make anything you want:

```
function show(x){
    var $warning = $('#warning');
    $warning.show();
    setInterval(function(){

       if (!$warning.data('red')) { //if it's not red, make it red

          $warning.css('background-color', 'red');
          $warning.data('red', true);
       } else { //if it's red, make it transparent

          $warning.css('background-color', 'transparent');
          $warning.data('red', null);
       }
    }, 500);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

In your example show the div, but never hide to blink.
You can use jquery.delay() to make the blink effect.

```
<script> 
   function show(x){ 
      $('#warning').show().delay(500).hide();
     setTimeout(show, 500); 
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution is relying on the additional jQuery UI library:

```js
$('.buttons').on('click', function() {

  $("#warning").effect("pulsate", 1000, function() {
    $(this).show();
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<a class="buttons" href="#">join us</a>
<div id="warning" style="display:none;">SHOW THIS DIV ...</div>
```